# Можно ли в C# проект зашить код python?

Tags: c#, python

У меня есть приложение на C# можно ли в него зашить python скрипт?
Чтобы он сразу подгружался с кодом?

Comment: `new Process("MyTest.py").Start()` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скачиваем [IronPython](http://ironpython.net) подключаем библиотеки **IronPython.dll**, **Microsoft.Scripting.dll**.

**Применение:**

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
engine.Execute(@"Script Python");
```

Answer (score 5):

http://ironpython.net/ компилит питонный код в .NET bytecode.

Думаю, ты ищещь именно это.

Если нужно запустить питонный код на винте: `new Process("MyTest.py").Start()`, как подсказал Digital Core,  но питон должен быть установлен на компьютере.

Comment: Какая проблема импортировать две библиотеки `IronPython.dll`, `Microsoft.Scripting.dll`, инициализировать `var engine = Python.CreateEngine();`  и выполнить `engine.Execute(@"Script Python");` .

Comment: @DigitalCore Ну так дайте свою версию ответа, зачем писать в комментариях?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел очень интересную статью как вызвать метод написанный на Python в C#
[Cсылка на статью](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/dynamic-language-integration-in-a-c-world/)

Используется ***IronPython*** (тестировал NuGet версии 3.4.1)

**Файл calc.py**

```
class Calculator:
   def add(self, argA, argB):
      return argA+argB
   def sub(self, argA, argB):
      return argA-argB
```

**Файл Program.cs**

```
    using IronPython.Hosting; 
   
    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    dynamic exfile = engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Users\Григорий\source\repos\TestToR\TestToR\bin\Debug\net8.0\calc.py");
    dynamic calc = exfile.Calculator(); // Создаем объект класса Calculator

    double a = 7.5;
    double b = 2.5;
    double res;
    res = calc.add(a, b); // Выполняем метод add
```